# How to bind definition with Button in Tkinter to show a result in window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This code has to calculate coordinates to give 3 results. Now it's only a window with some inputs, but no action at all (I want the application to calculate formula which depends on different inputs).

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Oblicz wyznacznik, iloczyn wektorowy i roznice")

        vcmd = master.register(self.validate) # we have to wrap the command
        self.entry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, 
        '%P'))

        self.zamknij_button = Button(master, 
        text='Zamknij',command=master.quit)   
        **#show result**
        self.oblicz_button = Button(master, text='Oblicz', 
        command=lambda:self.update)      

# LAYOUT ONLY
        self.xa_label = Label(master, text="XA")
        self.xa_label.grid(row=0)
        self.ya_label = Label(master, text="YA")
        self.ya_label.grid(row=1)
        self.xb_label = Label(master, text="XB")
        self.xb_label.grid(row=2)
        self.yb_label = Label(master, text="YB")
        self.yb_label.grid(row=3)
        self.xp_label = Label(master, text="XP")
        self.xp_label.grid(row=4)
        self.yp_label = Label(master, text="YP")
        self.yp_label.grid(row=5)
        self.e7_label = Label(master, text="Wyznacznik =")
        self.e7_label.grid(row=7)
        self.e8_label = Label(master, text="Iloczyn wektorowy =")
        self.e8_label.grid(row=8)
        self.e9_label = Label(master, text="Roznica =")
        self.e9_label.grid(row=9)
        self.zamknij_button.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)
        self.oblicz_button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

        self.xa = Entry(master)
        self.ya = Entry(master)
        self.xb = Entry(master)
        self.yb = Entry(master)
        self.xp = Entry(master)
        self.yp = Entry(master)

        self.xa.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.ya.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.xb.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.yb.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.xp.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.yp.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.xa.insert(10, 6123456.123)
        self.ya.insert(10, 3123456.123)
        self.xb.insert(10, 6123459.123)
        self.yb.insert(10, 3123458.123)
        self.xp.insert(10, 6123457.123)
        self.yp.insert(10, 3123458.123)
```

#Important part

```
    def validate(self, new_text):
        if not new_text:  # the field is being cleared
            self.e7 = 0
            return True

        try:
            self.e7 = int(new_text)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

## most important part; I would like to connect formula with Button called "oblicz_button"

```
    def update(self):
            self.e7.values(xa, ya, xb, yb, xp, yp)
            self.e7= (xa * xb) + (xb * yp) + (xp * ya) - (ya * xb) - (yb 
            * xp) - (yp * xa)

            self.e7_label_text.set(self.e7)

root = Tk()
my_gui = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As input I will take variables: xa, xb, xp, ya, yb, yp (it should work with different numbers).
My desired output is a result I will get after substituting numbers to formula: (xa * xb) + (xb * yp) + (xp * ya) - (ya * xb) - (yb * xp) - (yp * xa)
A result should be shown as a real number in appliation window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Oblicz wyznacznik, iloczyn wektorowy i roznice")

        vcmd = master.register(self.validate) # we have to wrap the command
        self.entry = Entry(master, validate="key", validatecommand=(vcmd, 
        '%P'))

        self.zamknij_button = Button(master, 
        text='Zamknij',command=master.quit)   
        #show result**
        self.oblicz_button = Button(master, text='Oblicz', 
        command=lambda:self.update())      

# LAYOUT ONLY
        self.Wyz = DoubleVar() #used so that the value in the entry updates
        self.Ilo = DoubleVar() #used so that the value in the entry updates
        self.Roz = DoubleVar() #used so that the value in the entry updates
        self.xa_label = Label(master, text="XA")
        self.xa_label.grid(row=0)
        self.ya_label = Label(master, text="YA")
        self.ya_label.grid(row=1)
        self.xb_label = Label(master, text="XB")
        self.xb_label.grid(row=2)
        self.yb_label = Label(master, text="YB")
        self.yb_label.grid(row=3)
        self.xp_label = Label(master, text="XP")
        self.xp_label.grid(row=4)
        self.yp_label = Label(master, text="YP")
        self.yp_label.grid(row=5)
        self.e7_label = Label(master, text="Wyznacznik =")
        self.e7_label.grid(row=7)

        self.e7 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.Wyz)
        self.e7.grid(row = 7, column = 1) #layout for Wyz answer the textvariable makes it so that when the value of self.Wyz updates so does the result on GUI, same goes for other two, 

        self.e8_label = Label(master, text="Iloczyn wektorowy =")
        self.e8_label.grid(row=8)

        self.e8 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.Ilo) #use for Iloczyn
        self.e8.grid(row = 8, column = 1)

        self.e9_label = Label(master, text="Roznica =")
        self.e9_label.grid(row=9)

        self.e9 = Entry(master, textvariable = self.Roz) #use for Roznica
        self.e9.grid(row = 9, column = 1)

        self.zamknij_button.grid(row=10, column=1, sticky=W, pady=5)
        self.oblicz_button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

        self.xa = Entry(master)
        self.ya = Entry(master)
        self.xb = Entry(master)
        self.yb = Entry(master)
        self.xp = Entry(master)
        self.yp = Entry(master)

        self.xa.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.ya.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.xb.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.yb.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.xp.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.yp.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.xa.insert(10, 6123456.123)
        self.ya.insert(10, 3123456.123)
        self.xb.insert(10, 6123459.123)
        self.yb.insert(10, 3123458.123)
        self.xp.insert(10, 6123457.123)
        self.yp.insert(10, 3123458.123)
#Important part

    def validate(self, new_text):
        if not new_text:  # the field is being cleared
            self.Wyz.set(0)
            return True

        try:
            self.Wyz.set(int(new_text))
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def update(self):
        xa = float(self.xa.get()) #Entry.get retrieves the value in the entry field it is a string that needs to be converted
        ya = float(self.ya.get())
        xb = float(self.xb.get())
        yb = float(self.yb.get())
        xp = float(self.xp.get())
        yp = float(self.yp.get())

        #self.e7.values(xa, ya, xb, yb, xp, yp) 
        Wy_result = (xa * xb) + (xb * yp) + (xp * ya) - (ya * xb) - (yb * xp) - (yp * xa)

        self.Wyz.set(Wy_result)
        print ("Wyz = %f") %Wy_result

root = Tk()
my_gui = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very helpful. Anyway, I thought I will manage to add also: Il_result = -(xp-xa)*(yb-ya) + (yp-ya)*(xb-xa) and Roz_result = (Wy_result) - (Il_result), but I have an error: AttributeError: Calculator instance has no attribute 'Ilo_set'. My question is: how to implement properly the other formulae into my code?

Comment: Use the set function for those also, i.e `self.Roz.set(Roz_result)`, `self.Ilo.set(Il_result)`  where ever you defined your results

Comment: I did, the problem is, I guess, that it should be implemented here as well: 
 `def validate(self, new_text): \ if not new_text: \ self.Wyz.set(0) \ return True`. (In the "important part"). Something like  `self.Ilo.set(0)`, but no idea how to put it together.

Comment: It appears so, but it all depends on your end result. The validate seems as those it is checking if the entry is empty, but your new_text referred to anything.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you took the time to explain what you did to fix the problem. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the code in the question line by line and character by character.

Comment: I added comments at points where the changes are. But you are right, more is better.